# Android Task Threads and the UI

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, asynchronous

I am trying to run the import of a large XML file in the background/asynchronously/... - in other words I'm trying to get it off the UI thread.

My code is as follows:

```
private string ImportXML()
    {
        string returnFile = null;
        ParseXML.ParseXML parsexml = new ParseXML.ParseXML (chosenFile);

        ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.SetMessage(GetString(Resource.String.ImportXML));
        progress.Indeterminate = true;
        progress.Show();

        Task xmlTask = new Task (() => returnFile = parsexml.ProcessXML());

        xmlTask.Start();

        while (!(xmlTask.IsCompleted || xmlTask.IsCanceled || xmlTask.IsFaulted))
            progress.Show();

        xmlTask.Wait(); 

        progress.Hide();

        return returnFile;
    }
```

The code appears to be running either synchronously or still in the main UI thread as UI updates (which I'm temporarily trying to do with the while loop) are not taking place - I don't get to see the progress at all.

The operation can take a good few seconds - up to 10 with some of my sample files - so I'm not keen to use AsyncTask as I believe it's not recommended for long-ish operations.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong with this please?

Comment: Use an async task, it is perfect for this. Are you sure your code is running in a separate thread? By that I mean is the method `ImportXML()` running in a separate thread?

Comment: of course you don't see updates using the NON-UI thread to update progress... you'd have to invoke the UI thread to do that.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Thanks for replying. I'm a little new to Android (and c#) development so I was under the impression that by calling ImportXML in this way I would force it to be in a separate thread. From your reply I guess this isn't the case?

Comment: No it's not. I will post an answer with an example `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you create a task to do some work in a non-UI thread.  Then you tell the UI thread to sit there and wait for that other task to finish.  You don't let it continue on or do any other work until that task is done.  This is blocking the UI thread, and it's no better than just doing the work right in the UI thread (the overhead actually makes it worse).

What you need to do is add a continuation to the task which can handle whatever work you want to do when the task finishes, and then *let the method end* so that the UI thread can continue on to do other work.

```
private Task<string> ImportXML()
{
    ParseXML.ParseXML parsexml = new ParseXML.ParseXML(chosenFile);

    ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.SetMessage(GetString(Resource.String.ImportXML));
    progress.Indeterminate = true;
    progress.Show();
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => parsexml.ProcessXML());
    task.ContinueWith(t => progress.Hide());
    return task;
}
```

Because this method must be asynchronous, allowing the UI thread to continue doing its work, it needs to return a `Task`, rather than the actual string.  The caller of this method can then add a continuation to the result of this method call to use the results.

Comment: @XaverKapeller So it's using C# 1.0?  Why in the world wouldn't a lambda work?

Comment: Thank you @Servy - I have made these modifications  to my ImportXML method to make it a task. In the method that calls this task I have the following: 

if (chosenFile.EndsWith(".xml", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    dbFile = ImportXML().Result; 

but having traced this through it appears that I am again blocking the thread by doing this.

Comment: @Yromulus That's correct; `Result` blocks until there is a result.  You should have the work that needs to use the result of this task itself be a continuation of this method's task.  That is what it means to have an asynchronous program.

Comment: Thanks @Servy - with your suggestions and some more research I have a working solution now - I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example `AsyncTask` to show you how to process data separate from the ui thread. This `AsyncTask` will load a `String` from the resources and set it to a `TextView`.

**IMPORTANT:** Normally you would NEVER need an `AsyncTask` to load a `String` from the resources. I just picked this as an example to show how to perform work in a separate thread.

For any `AsyncTask` there is just one thing to remember: You perform work in a separate thread, not in the ui thread. When the separate thread finishes there are no guarantees that the ui elements you are referencing still exists or even that your app is still running. Therefore if you reference an `Activity` or a `Context` or some ui element like a `TextView` or `Button` or any other complex object which might not be around anymore when the background thread finishes you have to use a `WeakReference`. `WeakReferences` are a clever way to get around this problem by allowing the object you are referencing to be garbage collected. In your `AsyncTask` you can then check if the object you need still exists and if yes perform your work without creating memory leaks. You use a `WeakReference` like this:

```
WeakReference<TextView> textViewReference = new WeakReference<TextView>(textView);
```

As you can see `WeakReference` is a generic type. If you want to reference a `TextView` like in this case you have to tell the `WeakReference` that by writing `<TextView>` after `WeakReference`. If you would reference a `Context` you would write `WeakReference<Context>` or if you reference a `SQliteDatabase` you would write `WeakReference<SQLiteDatabase>`. I guess you see the pattern going on here.
You pass the instance of the object you want to reference into the constructor of the `WeakReference`. That's the `(textView)` part of the example above. If you later want to get the instance back from the `WeakReference` you would do it like this:

```
TextView textView = textViewReference.get();
```

If the `TextView` you are referencing doesn't exist anymore `get()` will simply return null. So to check if the `TextView` still exists you can simply do it like this:

```
TextView textView = textViewReference.get();
if(textView != null) {
   // TextView still exists. 
} else {
   // TextView doesn't exist anymore. Most likely he has already been garbage collected.
}
```

If you understand this simple principle about how and when to use `WeakReferences` you should have no problem implementing an `AsyncTask`. I have explained anything else important about the `AsyncTask` with comments, just look through the source code. If you have any other questions please feel free to ask.

```
public class ExampleTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    // We use WeakReferences for all complex objects to prevent memory leaks
    private final WeakReference<TextView> textViewRefernece;
    private final WeakReference<Context> contextReference;

    // Primitives are fine. WeakReferences are not needed here.
    private int resourceId;

    public ExampleTask(Context context, TextView textView, int resourceId) {

        // We create the WeakReferences to our Context and to the TextView in which we want the result to appear.
        this.contextReference = new WeakReference<Context>(context);
        this.textViewRefernece = new WeakReference<TextView>(textView);

        this.resourceId = resourceId;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        // This method is executed on the ui thread just before the background thread starts.
        // You can perform some inital setup here but mostly you can leave this empty
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // This method is executed in a background thread. Here we can do our work.
        // First we have to get the context from the WeakReference
        Context context = contextReference.get();

        // Now we check if the Context still exists. If the context is null it has already been garbage collected.
        // That would happen for example if the app has been closed or even if it crashed.
        if(context != null) {

            // The context is not null which means it still exists we can continue and load the required String and return it
            return context.getString(this.resourceId);
        }

        // If something went wrong we return null.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        // This method is executed on the ui thread after the background thread is finished.
        // Here we get our final result and can set it to our TextView

        // First we check if the String result is null. If it is not null the background thread has finished successfully and we can continue.
        if(result != null) {

            // Here we get our TextView from the WeakReference
            TextView textView = textViewRefernece.get();

            // Now we check if the TextView still exists. If it is null it has already been garbage collected.
            // That would happen for example if the app has been closed while the AsyncTask has been running.
            // Or simply if the Fragment has been replaced or the Activity has changed.
            if(textView != null) {

                // The TextView is not null which means it still exists. We can now set our text.
                textView.setText(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged C#, not Java.  This is Java code.

Comment: I didn't look well enough at the question. He never mentions he is using Xamarin or anything similar. But no as soon as you are holding the reference after `get()` it can't be garbage collected anymore because you are again holding the reference directly.

Comment: Thanks @XaverKapeller - I'm sorry I wasn't a bit more detailed in explaining that I am using Xamarin and C#. I will try the C# example that Servy has given before I try the Async task example you have given me.